# In Texture Paint mode, is there a way to paint a desired color over another color in ONE click/stroke?

Tags: texture-painting

I'm new to Texture Painting and I've realized that trying to overlap one color with another in ONE click/drag will result in a shading effect that gives you a slightly weaker version of the intended color unless you overlap the color multiple times. Here is an image to better illustrate what I'm trying to achieve (the red circle).
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mainly play with the strength of the brush and with the brush shape itself :

[image]

Comment: I've been blending 18 hrs straight and didn't even notice that haha... Awkward.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try **accumulate**, it uses a different way of blending colors, always keeping them opaque on top of each other:

[image: accumulate]